# Can Velocity ResourceTool object be made aware of the current request?

Tags: apache, spring, velocity

I sub-classed `ResourceTool.java` and overrode one of the `get()` example:

```
public class MySubClassedResourceTool extends ResourceTool {

   @Override
   public Object get(String arg0, String[] arg1, Locale arg2) {
    Locale locale = //... get me here a locale from Request or Session object;  
    return super.get(arg0, arg1, locale);
   }
}
```

I need to replace the `Locale` with the `Locale` object coming from the request or session.

Does `ResourceTool` have access to or can it be made in any way to have direct access to client's `Request` or `Session` object?

Answer (score 0):

http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ResourceTool.html

Yes, just put it in request scope and it will have (and use) access to the request's locale automatically.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it didn't work. I'm using the ResourceTool v2.0 and I use scope="request". Also I set the locale of the Request object to a different one but the ResourceTool is still using the system locale i.e. en_CA and not the one I set on the Request object.

Comment: To sum it up: the Request object has Locale = "en_US" and the LocaleConfig.configure(ValueParser values) has values.getLocale(ToolContext.LOCALE_KEY) = "en_CA". I have no idea why it's setting it to en_CA when the Request object has it as en_US. Any suggestion as to how to find out who and where in the VelocityTools the locale is changed to en_CA? I couldn't find it after hours of looking. Thanks.

Comment: Bring the question to the Velocity user list.  I have extremely limited time for Apache stuff these days, but maybe someone else there can answer.